# Parse an expression using preg_match

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, match

I'm trying to parse the following by using preg_match:

```
2020|9 digits number|date hour|word|word
```

As an example:

```
2020|123456789|01/04/2011 09:09:37|Basketball|sms
```

I'm doing:

```
$regex  = '2020|/[0-9]+\|[a-zA-Z]+\|[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{4}.*/';
return !(preg_match($regex,$value));
```

But I'm getting the error `Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash`, and I'm not getting even close to it.

Can you please give me a hand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regex has a few problems

- Escape the first `|`.
- Move the first `/` to the beginning of the regex. The `/` is a delimiter that marks the beginning and end of a regex.
- Remove the `[a-zA-Z]+` as that matches a word where your definition doesn't have one.

This should work:

```
$regex  = '/2020\|[0-9]+\|[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{4}.*/';
return !(preg_match($regex,$value));
```

You could also use `#` as your delimiter to avoid the need to escape the literal `/`s.

```
$regex  = '#2020\|[0-9]+\|[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{4}.*#';
```

It is also not as strict as your definition of what the string should look like. I suggest making the following improvements:

- Match exactly 9 digits, not 1+, by using `[0-9]{9}`.
- Match the timestamp with `[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}`.
- Match the last two words with `\w+\|\w+`.
- Add `^` and `$` anchors to force a match of the full string.

Putting that all together gives us:

```
$regex  = '#^2020\|[0-9]{9}\|[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{4}\s[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}\|\w+\|\w+$#';
```

See it [on rubular](http://www.rubular.com/r/IPLO64CcSj).

Comment: Yes I think so, the error says: "Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash". But I cannot make it, I cannot scape the thing, can you help me with it? Thanks!

Comment: marcog, I'm getting all the lines of the file in return .. but it  should only show the errors, the lines that are not equal to the expression  .. that's estrange ..

Comment: @user You'll have to give an example. We can't guess what's going wrong.

Comment: If $regex  = '#^2020\|[0-9]{9}\|[a-zA-Z]+\|[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{4}\s[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}\|\w+\|\w+$#';
 matches this structure 2020|123456789|01/04/2011 09:09:37|Basketball|sms why return !(preg_match($regex,$value));
is returning all the lines in the file? The majority of them are built like the example, this should return the errors, the ones that are not built like the example ..

Comment: @user You had a word group in there that shouldn't have been there. Tested and my latest works on that string.

Comment: @user Glad it worked for you. I recommend reading through http://www.regular-expressions.info/ if you're going to be writing more regular expressions.

Answer (score 7):

If `|` is your separator, and the data is always structured the way you describe, why not use `explode()` instead?

```
$array = explode ("|", $value);
echo $array[0]; // Will output "2020"
echo $array[1]; // Will output "123456789"
```

For this to work reliably, none of the columns must contain "|" as a content character. But you'd have that restriction with a regex, too.

If you're parsing whole files built like this, take a look at [`fgetcsv()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php).

Comment: Thanks for answering, and sorry because I may not have explained myself right: I'm checking a text file for other than the $regex. That will be and error, so I'm checking for errors.What I cannot make right is the expresion, I cannot match what I need. I get an error: "Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash ". Thanks again

Comment: @user no problem. So it's not the entire text file that has this structure?

Answer (score 1):

Perl compatible regular expressions must start and end with a delimiter (below, `%`). Your RE begins with "2", which PCRE interprets as a delimiter, hence the "Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash" error.

The expression I'd start with to check "2020|9 digits number|date hour|word|word" is `%^2020\|\d{9}\|\d{2}[-/]\d{2}[-/]\d{4} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\|\w+\|\w+$%`. Other than the date, the REs matching the fields are very simple: a predefined class (`\d` for digits, equivalent to `[0-9]`; `\w` for words, equivalent to `[A-Za-z0-9_]`) and a repetition (`{n}` means exactly *n*, `+` means 1 or more).

The date is matched by `\d{2}[-/]\d{2}[-/]\d{4} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}`. This uses the same elements as the other subpatterns, just has more of them. If you want to match more date formats, you'll either need to write a more complex RE, or extract the date and use (e.g.) `strtotime` to parse it.

If you wish to parse the whole string, rather than simply check it, follow Pekka's advice.